# Java AWT PopupMenu Korean/Asian characters do not display

Tags: java, awt

I've been asked to incorporate Korean, Chinese and Japanese into my program, which has proven difficult. I'm forced to use AWT instead of Swing due to issues with TrayIcon, however the AWT PopupMenu seems to refuse to recognise Asian characters entirely.

Here's a sample program to demonstrate the issue:

```
package awttest;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class AWTTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame( );
        frame.setSize( 400, 300 );
        frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout( ) );

        Button button = new Button( "Test" );
        button.addActionListener( ( ActionEvent e ) ->
        {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu( "Menu" );
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem( "\uc2dc\uba54\uc9c0" );

            popup.setFont( new Font( "Serif", 0, 12 ) );
            System.out.println( popup.getFont( ).canDisplay( '\uc2dc' ) ); // prints true

            popup.add( item ); // displays 3 boxes
            popup.add( new MenuItem( "English Text" ) ); // displays normally
            button.add( popup );
            popup.show( button, 0, 25 );
        } );

        frame.add( button );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }    
}
```

I've tried setting the font to one of the Windows fonts that comes with Korean support, such as Gulim or Dotum, but I have the same result. Even changing my computer's locale to Korea has no effect. Is there any way to make AWT PopupMenu support Asian characters?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro. java version "1.8.0_111", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14), Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Your program works for me.  I am running

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_172"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

on Fedora 27.

At least, this demonstrates that the problem is not in your code.  It is *probably* a configuration issue ...

---

I suggest that you look at these two Oracle resources, and see if there are discrepancies between your own system and what they say:

- [Supported Fonts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/font.html)
- [Font Configuration Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html)